# How to redirect post request in aiohttp?

Tags: python, aiohttp

I'm trying to make a simple service, which can download a file from a post request and then redirect it to another service. How can I pass my file through?

I tried using HTTPFound, but I don't know how to pass the file through:

```py
raise web.HTTPFound(
        location='some_url_to_redirect',
        headers=request.headers,
        body=request.content,
   )
```

```py
from aiohttp import web, MultipartReader

async def store_files_handler(request):
    reader = MultipartReader.from_response(request)
    field = await reader.next()
    file_name = field.filename
    file_path = f"{FOLDER}/file_name"

    with open(file_path, 'wb') as file:
        while True:
            chunk = await field.read_chunk()
            if not chunk:
                break
            file.write(chunk)

    raise web.HTTPFound(
        location='some_url_to_redirect',
        headers=request.headers,
        body=reader,
    )

def register(app):
    app.add_routes([web.post('/store', store_files_handler)])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, i decided to use, code 307, so it will be:

```py
web.HTTPTemporaryRedirect('some_url_to_redirect')

it can redirect POST request
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really send content with a 302 redirect response (most browsers will just ignore it and redirect). The target location must serve the file. So you need to extend your router with that location and serve the file there.

```py
app.add_routes([web.post('/store', store_files_handler)])
app.add_routes([web.static('/location_to_file', 'path_to_static_folder')])
```

Or you could serve it directly from `/store` endpoint, whichever fits your design

- https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_quickstart.html#redirects
- https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/web_advanced.html#static-file-handling